# JFrame Text Size

Tags: java, text, jframe, size

I have been working to try and make a JFrame that has text in the middle that is really big, but every attempt I've made to change the size of the text has just resulted in teeny tinny little words in the corner of the screen.

```
public class StuffMost {
    public static JLabel three = new JLabel();
    public static JFrame one = new JFrame();
    public static JButton four = new JButton();

    public static void seconday() {
        one.setVisible(true);
        one.setResizable(true);

        one.setDefaultCloseOperation(one.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        one.setSize(1280, 800);
        one.setTitle("Hello! Welcome to my window. You Shall Never Leave.");
        one.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        three.setText("Dont");
        one.add(three);
        three.setSize(900, 300);
        one.add(four);
    }

}
```

Comment: which text you want to make bigger ?

Comment: Add this line on your code: three.setFont(new Font("Bold",100,100));

Answer (score 0):

Do not use setSize on the Label, for that does not change the font. If you want to make the font bigger then you would use:

```
three.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD,75));
```

if you wanted a different font, then you could change it to "Arial" or something like that, if you don't want it bolded, then change the second parameter to Font.PLAIN, and the last parameter is the font size, which in this case is 75